# Youtube Ui Fixed Home bar

Tags: reactjs, sass

If we ever open you tube desktop you will find two component inside home feed on left there is side bar and on right there is videos section.
if i scroll on that individual component it is scroll able like you tube but the problem is on you tube the home component is fixed it not move whole div.
How can i make my home component fixed
[image]

```js
#SIDEBAR

import React from "react";
import "./sidebar.scss";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import ExploreOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExploreOutlined";
import SubscriptionsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SubscriptionsOutlined";
import VideoLibraryOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VideoLibraryOutlined";
import HistoryOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HistoryOutlined";
import WatchLaterOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/WatchLaterOutlined";
import ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAltOutlined";
import LogoutIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Logout";

function SideBar({ toggleSidebar }) {
  return (
    <div className={toggleSidebar ? "sidebar toggle" : "sidebar"}>
      <div
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "0.8px", backgroundColor: "black" }}
      ></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <HomeIcon></HomeIcon>
          <span>Home</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ExploreOutlinedIcon></ExploreOutlinedIcon>
          <span>Explore</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <SubscriptionsOutlinedIcon></SubscriptionsOutlinedIcon>
          <span>Subscriptions</span>
        </li>
        <div className="hr_line"></div>
        <li>
          <VideoLibraryOutlinedIcon></VideoLibraryOutlinedIcon>
          <span>Library</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <HistoryOutlinedIcon></HistoryOutlinedIcon>
          <span>History</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <WatchLaterOutlinedIcon></WatchLaterOutlinedIcon>
          <span>Watch Later</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon></ThumbUpAltOutlinedIcon>
          <span>Liked Videos</span>
        </li>
        <div className="hr_line"></div>
        <li>
          <LogoutIcon></LogoutIcon>
          <span>Log Out</span>
        </li>
        <div className="hr_line"></div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;


#HOME
import React from "react";
import "./home.scss";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;


#App
import "./App.scss";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import SideBar from "./components/sidebar/SideBar";
import Home from "./components/home/Home";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [toggleSidebar, setToggleSidebar] = useState(false);

  const handleSidebarCollapse = () => setToggleSidebar((value) => !value);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header handleSidebarCollapse={handleSidebarCollapse}></Header>
      <div className="content">
        <SideBar
          handleSidebarCollapse={handleSidebarCollapse}
          toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar}
        ></SideBar>
        <Home></Home>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
#HOME CSS
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
  }
  scrollbar-width: none;
}


#SideBAR CSS
.sidebar {
  width: 260px;
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.98);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;

  &.toggle {
    // transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2342;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
  }

  scrollbar-width: none;

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;

    .hr_line {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      height: 0.8px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }

    li {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0.6rem 1.5rem;
      margin: 0.2rem 0;
      cursor: pointer;

      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(113, 113, 113, 0.3);
      }

      span {
        margin-left: 1rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.4px;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1224px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 90px;

    ul {
      li {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      span {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}

// @media (max-width: 520px) {
//   .sidebar {
//     transform: translateX(-100%);
//     position: fixed;
//     z-index: 695;
//   }
// }


#APP css
.content {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the body when the sidebar is shown and make the overflow hidden and remove it when the sidebar closes.

this makes sure the document's scrollbar will stay hidden when sidebar is open

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!toggleSidebar ) return document.body.classList.remove("no-scroll");
    document.body.classList.add("no-scroll");
  }, [toggleSidebar ]);
```

And the `no-scroll` css class will look like this

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```